# tune_bayes() function error - All of the models failed--see the .notes column

Tags: r, random-forest, hyperparameters, tidymodels

I am trying to replicate the examples of hyperparameter tuning using Bayesian searching from this site: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/bayesian-hyperparameters-optimization/ , and when running my code, received the following error: Error: All of the models failed. See the .notes column. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Here is my current code. The error occurs when running the code starting on the tuned_PI line. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. I am very new to the tidymodels package and hyperparameter tuning.

```
training_index <- sample(nrow(data)*0.70)
test_index     <- setdiff(seq(1:nrow(data)), training_index )

# Get the training data and test data
training_data  <- data[training_index, ]
test_data      <- data[test_index, ]

model_tune <- rand_forest(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", seed=222) %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
set.seed(1234)
folds <- vfold_cv(training_data, v=5, strata = DEATH_EVENT)
tune_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(model_tune) %>% 
  add_formula(DEATH_EVENT~.)
tuned_PI <- tune_wf %>% 
  tune_bayes(resamples = folds,
        param_info=parameters(mtry(range = c(1,10)), min_n(range = c(1,10)), trees(range = c(480,540))),
             metrics=metric_set(sensitivity),
           objective=prob_improve(trade_off = 0.01))
```

Comment: Note: I did get it to run after converting my outcome variable to a factor, however, it will not finish, and now gives the error message: x Optimization stopped prematurely; returning current results.
Error: `best` should be a single, non-missing numeric

Comment: Can you create a [small reproducible example](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) that demonstrates your problem? Unfortunately there isn't enough information here to ascertain what has gone wrong.